# Man ignoring manpath

Tags: man

I have written my own manpage, but as it is going to be present on a large number of company computers and I want to update it often, I would like it to be situated in folder shared between these computers.

Therefore, I have added this folder to  `manpath`, using `/etc/man.config` - when I type `manpath` in a terminal, I get the following output: `/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man/en:/usr/share/man:/online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq-documentation`.

This is correct, the last path is the one I want my manpage to be situated in. The problem is, this path is being ignored for some reason. When I type `man my_program`, I get `No manual entry for my_program`. If I put my manpage file into one of the other paths instead (for example `/usr/local/share/man`), the manpage displays properly following the `man my_program` command. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my `/etc/man.config` :

```
#
# Generated automatically from man.conf.in by the
# configure script.
#
# man.conf from man-1.6f
#
# For more information about this file, see the man pages man(1)
# and man.conf(5).
#
# This file is read by man to configure the default manpath (also used
# when MANPATH contains an empty substring), to find out where the cat
# pages corresponding to given man pages should be stored,
# and to map each PATH element to a manpath element.
# It may also record the pathname of the man binary. [This is unused.]
# The format is:
#
# MANBIN        pathname
# MANPATH       manpath_element [corresponding_catdir]
# MANPATH_MAP       path_element    manpath_element
#
# If no catdir is given, it is assumed to be equal to the mandir
# (so that this dir has both man1 etc. and cat1 etc. subdirs).
# This is the traditional Unix setup.
# Certain versions of the FSSTND recommend putting formatted versions
# of /usr/.../man/manx/page.x into /var/catman/.../catx/page.x.
# The keyword FSSTND will cause this behaviour.
# Certain versions of the FHS recommend putting formatted versions of
# /usr/.../share/man/[locale/]manx/page.x into
# /var/cache/man/.../[locale/]catx/page.x.
# The keyword FHS will cause this behaviour (and overrides FSSTND).
# Explicitly given catdirs override.
#
# FSSTND
FHS
#
# This file is also read by man in order to find how to call nroff, less, etc.,
# and to determine the correspondence between extensions and decompressors.
#
# MANBIN        /usr/local/bin/man
#
# Every automatically generated MANPATH includes these fields
#
MANPATH /usr/man
MANPATH /usr/share/man
MANPATH /usr/local/man
MANPATH /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH /usr/X11R6/man
MANPATH /online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq-documentation
#
# Uncomment if you want to include one of these by default
#
# MANPATH   /opt/*/man
# MANPATH   /usr/lib/*/man
# MANPATH   /usr/share/*/man
# MANPATH   /usr/kerberos/man
#
# Set up PATH to MANPATH mapping
#
# If people ask for "man foo" and have "/dir/bin/foo" in their PATH
# and the docs are found in "/dir/man", then no mapping is required.
#
# The below mappings are superfluous when the right hand side is
# in the mandatory manpath already, but will keep man from statting
# lots of other nearby files and directories.
#
MANPATH_MAP /bin            /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /sbin           /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin        /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/sbin       /usr/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/bin      /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/local/sbin     /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/X11R6/bin      /usr/X11R6/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin/X11        /usr/X11R6/man
MANPATH_MAP /usr/bin/mh     /usr/share/man
#
# NOAUTOPATH keeps man from automatically adding directories that look like
# manual page directories to the path.
#
#NOAUTOPATH
#
# NOCACHE keeps man from creating cache pages ("cat pages")
# (generally one enables/disable cat page creation by creating/deleting
# the directory they would live in - man never does mkdir)
# 
#NOCACHE
#
# Useful paths - note that COL should not be defined when
# NROFF is defined as "groff -Tascii" or "groff -Tlatin1";
# not only is it superfluous, but it actually damages the output.
# For use with utf-8, NROFF should be "nroff -mandoc" without -T option.
# (Maybe - but today I need -Tlatin1 to prevent double conversion to utf8.)
#
# If you have a new troff (version 1.18.1?) and its colored output
# causes problems, add the -c option to TROFF, NROFF.
#
TROFF       /usr/bin/groff -Tps -mandoc
NROFF       /usr/bin/nroff -c -mandoc 2>/dev/null
EQN     /usr/bin/geqn -Tps
NEQN        /usr/bin/geqn -Tutf8
TBL     /usr/bin/gtbl
# COL       /usr/bin/col
REFER       /usr/bin/grefer
PIC     /usr/bin/gpic
VGRIND      
GRAP        
PAGER       /usr/bin/less -is
BROWSER     /usr/bin/less -is
HTMLPAGER   /bin/cat
CAT     /bin/cat
#
# The command "man -a xyzzy" will show all man pages for xyzzy.
# When CMP is defined man will try to avoid showing the same
# text twice. (But compressed pages compare unequal.)
#
CMP     /usr/libexec/man-cmp.sh
#
# Compress cat pages
#
COMPRESS    /usr/bin/lzma
COMPRESS_EXT    .lzma
#
# Default manual sections (and order) to search if -S is not specified
# and the MANSECT environment variable is not set (1x-8x sections are used by
# xorg packages).
#
MANSECT     1:1p:8:2:3:3p:4:5:6:7:9:0p:n:l:p:o:1x:2x:3x:4x:5x:6x:7x:8x
#
# Default options to use when man is invoked without options
# This is mainly for the benefit of those that think -a should be the default
# Note that some systems have /usr/man/allman, causing pages to be shown twice.
#
#MANDEFOPTIONS  -a
#
# Decompress with given decompressor when input file has given extension
# The command given must act as a filter.
#
.gz     /usr/bin/gunzip -c
.bz2        /usr/bin/bzip2 -c -d
.lzma       /usr/bin/unlzma -c -d
.z      
.Z      /bin/zcat
.F      
.Y      
#
# Enable/disable makewhatis database cron updates.
# If MAKEWHATISDBUPDATES variable is uncommented
# and set to n or N, cron scripts 
# /etc/cron.daily/makewhatis.cron
# /etc/cron.weekly/makewhatis.cron
# will not update makewhatis database.
# Otherwise the database will be updated.
# 
#MAKEWHATISDBUPDATES    n
```

Comment: What's the full path to the manpage file you created? Does running `man -u` help or produce interesting output?

Comment: The full path is /online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq-documentation/CLI.1.gz .

Comment: Running man -u returns "invalid option" and prints help.

Comment: Ah. What unix variant are you running? What man implementation does it use — maybe you have a `/usr/bin/man` that has a different configuration from `/usr/local/bin/man` or something?

Comment: The PC is running SLC6. Running `which man` returns `/usr/bin/man`. There's no man binary in `/usr/local/bin`. I'm not sure how to find out which man implementation it uses - upon asking for help, I get a "man, version 1.6f" header.

Comment: Try putting it in `/online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq-documentation/man1/CLI.1.gz .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each directory in `MANPATH` is the root of a *manual page hierarchy*. Under that directory are one or more `mansection` directories<sup>1</sup>, such as `man1`, and in each of those directories there are zero or more troff source files named `commandname.section`, possibly with an added `.Z` or `.gz` suffix, in your case `CLI.1.gz`.

So if your `man.config` has a line

```
MANPATH /online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq-documentation
```

then you'd copy your man page troff source code to a path such as

```
/online/RCCARS/compass-rccars-daq-documentation/man1/CLI.1.g‌​z
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Depending on your OS, you may also have `catsection`, `fmtsection`, and `smansection` directories.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am *very* late ... and probably after 5 years you found a solution ;-) already.

But you also should check the file and directory permissions of the whole path to the man page you like to provide/view.

The man command is a bit 'picky' about the file permissions - you will be able to vi/cat the man page with your account, but still man cannot display it.